# sql query: build from table row by Id, that would be followed in order Sym Pos

Tags: mysql

a table:

```
+-----+-----+----+ 
| Sym | Pos | Id | 
+-----+-----+----+ 
| a   | 0   | 0  | 
| b   | 1   | 0  | 
| c   | 2   | 0  | 
| a   | 0   | 1  | 
| d   | 1   | 1  | 
| b   | 0   | 2  | 
+-----+-----+----+
```

need to build from this table row by Id, that would be followed in order Sym Pos.
In this case, that would have:

```
+-----+----+ 
| str | Id | 
+-----+----+ 
| abc | 0  | 
| ad  | 1  | 
| b   | 2  | 
+-----+----+
```

Comment: What is the purpose of the column `Pos`. Should it always contain 0? If it is not always zero then under what condition does it have a different value.

Comment: Pos - symbol(Sym) position in `str`

Comment: Actually I meant what is the purpose of that column *in the output*, sorry for not making that clear.

Comment: value of `Pos` does not matter. important to get `str`.

Comment: @MarkByers I've updated the question based on the OP comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use GROUP BY and the MySQL specific aggregate function [GROUP_CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat):

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(Sym ORDER BY Pos SEPARATOR '') AS str, Id
FROM yourtable
GROUP BY id
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at using [GROUP_CONCAT()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat)